# Pool(num_cores) crashes with PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So I had the following code which seemed to work perfectly until I reinstalled Python and Pycharm:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Pool
num_cores = cpu_count()
pool = Pool(num_cores)
```

This gives out the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\Dropbox\\3_Master_Program\\Master_Thesis\\1_Code\\<input>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
        new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError    : _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)[WinError 5] Access is denied
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)PermissionError    
_winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: : [WinError 5] Access is denied[WinError 5] Access is denied
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError:     new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
[WinError 5] Access is denied
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\patri\Miniconda3\envs\master_thesis\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I have no clue why this is happening and I would appreciate any advice. I have to mention that I am doing this in a conda environment that I have created.

EDIT: Apparently this is related with my conda environment. With the root environment this error does not appear